# Stock management problems with downloadable products added programmatically (Magento 1.9.2.2)

Tags: search, stock

Basically I'm trying to add downloadable products automatically. I started using some code snippets from Magento StackExchange, which worked partitially. But in the admin panel the quantity field is  just empty (it isn't even showing a 0) which is the apparent reason for the products not showing up in the search.

I've already tried really many code snippets to add a stock item to the products, but none of them really worked, for example:

```
$stockItem = Mage::getModel('cataloginventory/stock_item')->loadByProduct($new);

$stockItem->setData(array(
                   'use_config_manage_stock' => 0
                   'manage_stock'=>1, 
                   'min_sale_qty'=>1,
                   'max_sale_qty'=>2,
                   'is_in_stock' => 1,
                   'qty' => 999
               )
);
$stockItem->save()
```

which throws a PDOException.

```
$product->setStockData(array(
            'use_config_manage_stock' => 0, 
            'qty' => 0, 
            'min_qty' => 0, 
            'use_config_min_qty' => 0, 
            'min_sale_qty' => 0, 
            'use_config_min_sale_qty' => 0, 
            'max_sale_qty' => 0, 
            'use_config_max_sale_qty' => 1, 
            'is_qty_decimal' => 0, 
            'backorders' => 0, 
            'notify_stock_qty' => 0, 
            'is_in_stock' => 1
    ));
```

which does nothing.

I've even tried to edit the SQL database manually, which made a 0 show up in the QTY field, but the products still didn't appear in the search.

However, if I edit and save the product in the admin panel, everything works which made me try to access the admin panel programmatically, which didn't work either.

Does anyone know if it's possible to disable the stock management entirely, so I don't have to care about this stuff?